# Newbie question: Cant rise vehicle from front jack point to place jack stands on sides

Tags: honda, fit

[image]

(not my car in the picture)

I have a 2008 Honda Fit with the following gear:

- a 2 ton jack with a 30 cms clearance
- two 3 ton jack stands that have 32 cms of minimum height.

Background: i cant buy a new hydraulic jack nor jack stands because they are awfully expensive here and im not rich enough. The next tier of hydraulic jacks cost minimum 4 times more that what i've already paid. Being that said...

First problem is that my jack isnt long enough to reach the fron jack point which is located in the middle, behind the engine, almost where the doors hinges are.

I cant jack from weld pinch on sides because then i cant put the jackstands.

I cant buy ramps for now because they cost almost like a new jack (of the expensive ones. u$300 so you have an idea.)

I will try to reach the middle jack point from behind the front wheels, but then i also have the problem that the jack doesnt raise the vehicle enough to place the jack stands, although i made a 10 cm wooden base to place the jack onto.

My question is: are there other safer spots in a honda fit 2008 that i can use to raise the car and place the jack stands? I thought of using the bolts that hold the control arm of the front wheels, but im not experienced.

UPDATE:

I've been told by a buddy that i can raise the sides from the control arm bolts and that he always uses this points to jack up the car from the sides and then put jack stands on the pinch welds:

[image]

[image]

I've seen mechanics doing it on the street in other cars.

Is this okey?

Comment: Do you have or could get any pieces of wood (2x4 or 4x4) you can place between the jack and the frame of the vehicle? This would get you extra height out of your jack. An extra 3.5" of clearance would get it done for you, I'm sure.

Comment: Yes. It seems I don't have any other solution. I live in an apartment so I will have to find a place to put the ramps while I don't use them.

Comment: @Jh62 store them with your 2 hydraulic jacks...

Comment: did the vehicle not come with a jack? You can use that too.  What makes you think that spot in the center is the only jack point? Im sure they dont expect you to use that to change a tire.

Comment: Yes. But my question was about jacking the vehicle from elsewhere since my jack cant reach the middle jack point and if i lift from sides i cant put the jack stands. I dont know if the control arm bolts are safe enough. I've been told that they are, but i dont want to cause any damage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common issue, and here are various solutions that I have personally implemented to get around this restriction:

1. Build your own ramps. Get pieces of wood that are at least 2x8 (make sure they are wider than your tires). Each ramp will need 3 pieces, each about 1 foot shorter than the next, and cut the edge on a 45 degree angle. The picture below is 1 of 4 identical ramps I've built. Two of my vehicles weigh about double what your Fit weighs, so don't worry. I used 2x12 boards that fell off the fence :)
   [image]
2. Get a proper jack. You mentioned jacks with a higher jacking height are expensive. This is true of trolley jacks. Find yourself a bottle jack. They don't have wheels, but they can lift more weight and they can lift higher. I picked up a 6-ton bottle jack for $12 I believe, and it goes higher than my trolley jack.
3. Use a piece of wood between your jack and vehicle. As suggested by Paulster, get a thick piece of wood to give you more height. I've done this, and then I got scared the wood would crack and bought a bottle jack.

Comment: And I thought you were going to say “two boards that fell of the back of a lorry” :). But those ramps are very neat  - i did similar, but made a shallower angle 30 or so...

Comment: Thanks. I have some wooden platforms to give the jack more height and yours are very useful tips, but my question was more like what other places are strong enough (on this model) to jack from there, like using the control arm to put the jack so I can place the stands under the pinch welds.

Comment: Our points were made so that you raise the height of the vehicle allowing you to use the existing jacking points without stressing other components that may not be designed to take the load - some of the suspension arms can bend very easily...